# can a java applet save files?

Tags: java

i just want to know if it is at all possible to make a java applet save a file to the web server it is being hosted off of.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An applet runs on the client side, not on the server. Therefore, for it to be able to save something on the server, it must contact it (using FTP or whatever) just like any other program.

Comment: how would i go about contacting it via ftp using java. (i just got done with my computer sciences class and we had to use books from java V1.4.5; the only new java stuff i've learned are timers and arraylists.

Comment: FTP is just an example. My point was that an applet doesn't get any special treatment just because it resides on the server, because when it is run it's on the client's side. Anyway, if your server is also an FTP server and you want a way to connect to it using Java, you could use the commons net library (http://commons.apache.org/net/) which includes support for the FTP protocol.